# back to specific screen instead of the first screen react-native-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

When I tap on back button or execute `this.props.navigation.goBack()`, I go back to my first screen instead of the first screen.

here is my App.js were my navigator is implemented:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator({
          info: {
          screen: CtrlInfoStart,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      },
          mascotChoice: {
          screen: CtrlMascotChoice,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      },
          optionScreen: {
          screen: CtrlOptions,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      },
          welcomeScreen: {
          screen: CtrlWelcome,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      },
          preview: {
          screen: CtrlPreviewMap,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      },
          map: {
          screen: CtrlMap,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      },
          pointOfInterest: {
          screen: CtrlPI,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      },
          quizz: {
          screen: CtrlQuizz,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
      }
      }));

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator/>
    </View>
    );
  }
};
```

I use `this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeScreen');` to navigate between screens and `this.props.navigation.goBack()` to go back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import `BackHandler` from react native,

in `componentdidmount` bind `backhandler` event using `BackHandler.addEventListner()`

see this,

```
componentDidmount=()=>{
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
};

  handleBackButton = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeScreen');
    return true;
  };
```

And wherever you have used `goBack()` change it with `navigate("ScreenName")`

**EDIT**:

for unexpected behavior on other screens,
do this in which backhander is used.

```
import {NavigationEvents} "react-navigation";
```

in render inside the first component,

```
<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={this.compnentDidmount} onWillBlur={this.componentWillUnmount} />
```

if you have other logic in didmount and unmount then make separate methods for both and bind in `NavigationEvents`

Comment: Thanks you! That work, good hack. :)
What is the 'return true' used for and what does it do?

Comment: if not returned anything or returned false normal back button functionality will be fired not the one you coded in the method. It is useful if you have conditional back button behavior.

Comment: There is one problem on your solution. The current component is not unmounted when I execute 'this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeScreen');' , so the componentWillUnmount method are not executed. It causes weird behavior if I switch between different screens.

Comment: if for example I have a,b,c and d screens. Navigation should be a->b, b->c, b->d, b<-d, a<-c. If I go a,b and c, i come back to a (ok for now), then a->b, b->d, d->b (ok for now), but if I go to c, when I come back I will come back to b instead of a. Because the last EventListener was not removed, and the new is not added.

Comment: I have this error:

Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `CtrlWelcome`.

Comment: let me check once

Comment: my mistake, forgot {NavigationEvents}. see again

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Here is my code :

```
     export default class App extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return <AppContainer />;
      }
    };

    const stackMapPI = createStackNavigator({
        Map: {
            screen: CtrlMap,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                header: null
            })
        },
        PI: {
            screen: MainCtrlPIQuizz,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                header: null
            })
        }

    });

    const stackNav = createStackNavigator({
        Welcome: {
            screen: MainCtrlWelcome,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                header: null
            })
        },
        Option: {
            screen: CtrlOptions,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                header: null
            })
        },
        Map: {
            screen: stackMapPI,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
                header: null
            })
        }
    });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(stackNav);
```